# Create a list of the duplicate items in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I'm using a set to get a list of duplicate items from an ArrayList (which is populated from a database)

```
void getDuplicateHashTest() {
        List<BroadcastItem> allDataStoreItems  = itemsDAO.getAllItems();
        Set<BroadcastItem> setOfAllData = new HashSet<>(allDataStoreItems);
        List<BroadcastItem> diff = new ArrayList<>(setOfAllData);
        allDataStoreItems.removeAll(diff);
}
```

So at the last line, all the items which are not duplicates should be removed from the list of all items.

The problem is when I print `allDataStoreItems.size()` I get 0

The set and the sublist print the correct number of items.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? (I see no SQL there.)

Comment: How are the `BroadcastItem`s compared? Is there a possibility of all items being duplicates?
@Lino your question is better than mine, although I meant the same ;-)

Comment: how are the `hashcode` and `equals` method implemented?

Comment: Well, let's say you start with a list of numbers [2,6,7,2,6,3].  You put them into a set: {2, 6, 7, 3}.  Now you remove from the original list all the numbers equal to some number in the set; in other words remove all the 2's (leaving [6,7,6,3]), 6's ([7,8}), 7's ([8]) and 8s ([]).  Putting the list into a set didn't identify just the list elements that were duplicated, it identified every unique value in the list.

Comment: Collections.removeAll() removes all occurrences of the object. To be able to suggest an alternative, I would have to know if you want to remove all the occurrences of the duplicate, or reduce all of them to one instance?

Comment: `hashCode()` compares the hashCode of a String variable in BroadcastItem

Comment: The original list has a size of 1490. The size of the set/second list is 1477. so there are 13 duplicate elements, I want a list containing those duplicate elements.

Comment: @jarih because this question came about when I was dealing the issue described here stackoverflow.com/q/50381158/8098137 , I thought there maybe a solution at SQL level as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the [answer by jacobm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50391178/3182664) : The `Collection#removeAll` method will remove all occurrences of a particular element. But the alternative of creating a list and calling `remove` repeatedly is not really a good solution: On a `List`, the `remove` call will usually have O(n) complexity, so figuring out the duplicates like this will have quadratic complexity.

A better solution is the one that was already mentioned by [shamsher Khan in his answer (+1!)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50391401/3182664) : You can iterate over the list, and keep track of the elements that have already seen, using a `Set`.

This solution has a complexity of O(n).

It's not clear whether you want the *list* or the *set* of all duplicates. For example, when the input is `[1, 2,2,2, 3]`, should the result be `[2,2]` or just `[2]`? However, you can simply compute the *list* of duplicates, and make its elements unique in a second step, if necessary.

Here is an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class FindDuplicatesInList
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0,1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,8);

        List<Integer> duplicates = computeDuplicates(list);

        // Prints [1, 1, 3, 7, 7]
        System.out.println(duplicates);

        // Prints [1, 3, 7]
        System.out.println(makeUnique(duplicates));
    }

    private static <T> List<T> makeUnique(List<? extends T> list)
    {
        return new ArrayList<T>(new LinkedHashSet<T>(list));
    }

    private static <T> List<T> computeDuplicates(List<? extends T> list)
    {
        Set<T> set = new HashSet<T>();
        List<T> duplicates = new ArrayList<T>();
        for (T element : list)
        {
            boolean wasNew = set.add(element);
            if (!wasNew)
            {
                duplicates.add(element);
            }
        }
        return duplicates;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`List#removeAll` removes *all* occurrences of the given elements, not just one of each (in contrast to `List#remove` which only removes the first occurrence). So `setOfAllData` contains one copy of each element in your list, and then you remove all occurrences of each of those elements, meaning you'll always end up with an empty list.

To know how to fix this I'd need to know more about what you want the result to be. Do you want one copy of each element removed? If so, you could do that with:

```
List<BroadcastItem> allDataStoreItems  = itemsDAO.getAllItems();
Set<BroadcastItem> setOfAllData = new HashSet<>(allDataStoreItems);
setOfAllData.forEach(allDataStoreItems::remove);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the size of the original list is 1490. The size of the set/second list is 1477. so there are 13 duplicate elements, I want a list containing those duplicate elements.

Comment: Cool, what I posted will do that. Note that if you have the same element, say, 5 times, the result will contain 4 copies. If that's not what you want, you could put the result into a set afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a shot and let you know, This question came about because I'm dealing with the spill over from the issue described here https://stackoverflow.com/q/50381158/8098137

Answer (score 2):

Its simple if you want to store only duplicates find the below code.

```
Set<BroadcastItem> duplicates = new HashSet<>;
Set<BroadcastItem> allItems=new HashSet<> 
for(BroadcastItem b:allDataStoreItems){
      boolean x=allItems.add(b);
      if(x==false){
             duplicates.add(b); 
       }

}
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid iterating over the whole list. I think I will get whatever optimization that's backed into the conversion into Set<>

Comment: @Tlink You'll have to iterate over the list in one form or the other (maybe it's hidden in a `forEach` call or a constructor of a `Set`, but you're still doing it in any case)

Comment: Yes,  I'm just hoping to take advantage of any optimization backed into the conversion into Set

Comment: @Tlink If you are hoping for "optimizations" (in terms of performance), then you should first of all use an algorithm that is O(n) (as in this answer), and not an algorithm with O(n*n) (as in the currently accepted answer).

Comment: Thanks @Marco13 for pointing this out, will look deeper into this